# Custom source processing during optimization using r.js and requirejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, r.js

I wanted to know if there is any way I can customize how r.js processes the source code of javascript (or other) files during the merging/optimization of a project that uses require.js.

I need to apply some custom transformations, as for example handling some java-like annotations.

I'm looking for something similar to what is possible with browserify using the b.use().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. Is it actually possible using the "onBuildWrite" configuration parameter , and specifying a callback that is executed before each module is serialized. 
Something like:

```
var config = {
  baseUrl: 'src',
  onBuildWrite: function( name, path, contents ) {
    //Additional processing
    return contents;
  },
  modules: [{ 
    name: 'main' 
  }],
};
requirejs.optimize( config, function(results) {});
```